# simple bcrypt library for C

Tags: bcrypt

I'm looking for a simple to use cross-platform bcrypt library for C. I've searched around a couple places but nothing seems to compares to the ease of use of:

http://bcrypt.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/1eef0262901c#BCrypt.Net.Test%2fTestBCrypt.cs

Why are all the C implementations of this a nightmare compared to this .NET lib? Basically 2 functions is what I'm looking for.

1) Generate salt (return a string)

2) Hash string using a given salt & pw (return a string)

Answer (score 12):

Your C options for bcrypt seem to be:

- In OpenBSD: https://github.com/openbsd/src/blob/master/lib/libc/crypt/bcrypt.c
- In OpenWall: http://openwall.com/crypt/

The C implementations seem to be pretty straightforward to use.  The OpenBSD version looks like this:

```
char *bcrypt(const char *key, const char *salt);

char *bcrypt_gensalt(u_int8_t log_rounds);
```

P.S. Consider [scrypt](http://www.tarsnap.com/scrypt.html) for new code, if you are not restricted to using bcrypt only due to backward compatibility,

Comment: OpenBSD's files are also available on GH: https://github.com/openbsd/src/tree/master/lib/libc/crypt/bcrypt.c